# Async Image Load with React and Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, promise, redux-thunk

I am trying to create a simple message wall with a `<PostList />` container which displays a list of `<Post />` components.

```
 {posts.map(function (post: any) {
                return <Post key={post.postid} post={post} />;
            })}
```

I pass in a single post to the `Post` component which has a `<Avatar />` component that displays the users profile_pic inside it otherwise it displays a spinner.

**My question is how would I allow the components to display on screen and once the image is loaded replace the spinner with the retrieved image?**

I currently have the following Reducers and Actions:

**User Reducer:**

```
export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action : any){
    switch(action.type){
        case FETCH_USER_LOADING:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {isLoading: true});
        case FETCH_USER_DONE:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {users: state.users.concat(action.payload)});
}

    return state;
}
```

**User Actions:**

```
export function fetchUser(id: any) {
    return function (dispatch: any) {
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER_LOADING });
        return axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/users/${id}`, {
            headers: { token: localStorage.getItem('token') }
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                dispatch({type: FETCH_USER_DONE, payload: response.data});
                return response.data
            })
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Plenty of ways to do it.

One of which is to write your own component, where, a newly loaded image prompts a redraw in `componentDidMount`. Here's the full source code of a lazy image that you can use in your own project:

```
export default class LazyImage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loaded: false,
      error: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
      this.setState({
        loaded: true
      });
    };
    img.onerror = () => {
      this.setState({
        error: true
      });
    };
    img.src = this.props.src;
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.error) {
      return <img
        className={this.props.className}
        style={this.props.style}
        src={this.props.unloadedSrc}
        alt={this.props.alt} />
    } else if (!this.state.loaded) {
      return <img
        className={this.props.className}
        style={this.props.style}
        src={this.props.unloadedSrc}
        alt={this.props.alt} />
    }
    return <img
      className={this.props.className}
      style={this.props.style}
      src={this.props.src}
      alt={this.props.alt} />
  }
}
```

Which you would then use like so:

```
<LazyImage unloadedSrc={unloadedSrc} src={src} />
```

And then, you have the option of using a plethora of components that you can find just by googling the terms:

- "image load react"
- "react image lazy load"

Or any similar search term variety, thereof. My favourite component is [`react-imageloader`](https://github.com/hzdg/react-imageloader).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I created a library for lazy-loading images. It's main feature is to provide dynamic resizing of images, but it can also solve your problem.

https://github.com/peterlazzarino/react-adaptive-image

Here's an example you could use for lazy image loading that will resolve images from imgur. In my production app my image resolver points at an image server, but this is totally customize-able. You will just need to style the .header-image class to have a height and width.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { initImages } from 'react-adaptive-image';
import AdaptiveImage from 'react-adaptive-image';

initImages({
    imageResolver: function(image){
        return `https://i.imgur.com/${image.fileName}`
    }
})

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <AdaptiveImage backgroundImage className="header-image" fileName={'U6zWkcZ.png'} />
      );
    }
  }

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```